# iPhone X Topbar issue

Tags: ios, iphone-x

I am trying to convert my app in iPhone X compatible. I have a table in my viewcontroller with top layout 20 pixel. Now below is the screenshot for both the devices

iPhone 8
[image: iPhone 8]

iPhone X
[image: iPhone-X]

Now I am getting a white top bar with the coloured background in iPhone x.

In case if I am making a top layout for the table to 0, then cells overlaps topbar which I don't need.

Can anyone suggest what is the issue? Any suggestion would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the background of the main view controller's view to your desired color:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't conform to top layout but to the new safe area instead. Then everything should be fine.

Comment: can you please explain a little bit more?

Comment: You can read about it here: "All apps should adhere to the safe area and layout margins defined by UIKit, which ensure appropriate insetting based on the device and context." https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/overview/iphone-x/

Answer (score 2):

You can set background color for top bar (status bar) during application launch or during viewDidLoad of your view controller..

```
extension UIApplication {

    var statusBarView: UIView? {
        return value(forKey: "statusBar") as? UIView
    }

}

// Set upon application launch
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        return true
    }
}


or 
// Set it from your view controller
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    }

}
```

Here is result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add in Appdelegate.m

```
 if ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height >= 812)
     {
       [application setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
       self.window.clipsToBounds =YES;
       self.window.frame = CGRectMake(0,40,self.window.frame.size.width,self.window.frame.size.height-20);
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

as you can see this white space is basically the header , i don't know why it happens in iPhone X.
just try to override method

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section

then return 0.01f;

tried and worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

All answers provided here are good solutions, however, you can also do it by Autolayout as well by setting the Tableview's top constraint to safe area. Here is the screenshot.

This applies to same as the bottom constraint as well.

You can also refer to [this](https://medium.com/@kahseng.lee123/how-to-solve-the-most-common-interface-problems-when-adapting-apps-ui-for-iphone-x-44c0f3c80d84) guide for iPhoneX autolayout.

[image: Select the top constraint of Tableview and change it to SafeArea.Top]